# How do I make a method that detects all keystrokes?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Im a beginner so please bear with me... In my app using xcode and objective c, I would like to be able to detect when any key is pressed on the keyboard.  I have looked and found some code for detecting only certain keys but I would like to make a method detecting any key strokes ranging from esc to enter.  Ideally I would run a series of if statements any time any key is pressed.

```
//if a keystroke is detected run through this if statement

if([firstName.text length] < 1){

[firstNameLabel setHidden:NO];
 } else {
 [firstNameLabel setHidden:YES]; 
 }
 if([secondName.text length] < 1){

 [secondNameLabel setHidden:NO]; 
 } else {
 [secondNameLabel setHidden:YES]; 
 }
 if([email.text length] < 1){

 [emailLabel setHidden:NO]; 
 } else {
 [emailLabel setHidden:YES]; 
 }
 if([password.text length] < 1){

 [passwordLabel setHidden:NO]; 
 } else {
 [passwordLabel setHidden:YES]; 
 }
 if([passwordSame.text length] < 1){

 [passwordSameLabel setHidden:NO]; 
 } else {
 [passwordSameLabel setHidden:YES]; 
 }
 if([schoolName.text length] < 1){

 [schoolNameLabel setHidden:NO]; 
 } else {
 [schoolNameLabel setHidden:YES]; 
 }
 if([gradeLevel.text length] < 1){

 [gradeLevelLabel setHidden:NO]; 
 } else {
 [gradeLevelLabel setHidden:YES]; 
 }
```

Anyone have an idea of how you would write this method?

Comment: can this editing be inside a text field? or are you looking for more of a hot key or keyboard short cut set up?

Comment: I'm hoping to make an image appear after something has been written in a textbox. Ideally it would occur after the first character has been typed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: delegate method. You can use your logic and detect the keystrokes there.